# error TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword

Tags: angular, sqlite, nativescript

I am trying to implement SQLite db connection to my app.

I am using the below code in my "sqlite.service.ts" file

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
var Sqlite = require{"nativescript-sqlite"};

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {

    public getdbConnection() {
        return new Sqlite('Assets');
    }

    public closedbConnection() {
        new Sqlite('Assets')
            .then((db) => {
                db.close();
            })
    }
}
```

I have used the nativescript code sample "Groceries app using SQLite" as the basis of this code and that works without errors.

Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: Are you sure your _require path_ points to the sqlite package ?

Comment: @Florian, Can you elaborate what you mean by 'require path'

Comment: `require{"nativescript-sqlite"}`. your path is _nativescript-sqlite_, where is your package located ? Your package should be in `node_modules`, so ensure you point to your `node_modules` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `require("nativescript-sqlite")` instead of `require{"nativescript-sqlite"}`.